# Linux Script: How to check for any lines that starts with but not contain

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

I'm at the following directory...

/var/log/homes

and I would like a script to check for any lines starts with 'Error' and contains a word 'NotAuthorized' and not contains '13024' or '31071'.

Within /var/log/homes/, there are 700 files, but that doesn't matter...

Below is what I have...

```
#!/bin/bash

host=`hostname`
date=`date`
monitor='Error'
pattern='Error'
pattern2='NotAuthorized'
ignore=13024
ignore2=31071
logfile='/var/log/homes/*'
mailto='test@linux.com'

if [ -e $logfile ]
then
  if [ `grep -i "$pattern" "$pattern2" "$logfile" | grep -v $ignore $ignore  ]
  then
    echo "Errors found in $monitor at $date - see log $logfile on server $host for full details" |mail -s "ALERT - $errors in logs, please review" $mailto
  elif [ `grep -i "$pattern2" "$logfile" |wc -l` -lt 1 ]
   fi
else
   echo "Logfile $logfile doesn't exist on server $host at $date, this is probably     bad, please investigate" |mail -s "ALERT - $monitor monitor has an issue" $mailto
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
grep "^Error" $logfile | grep "NotAuthorized" | grep -v "13024" | grep -v "31071"
```

- `grep "^Error"`: get the lines starting ith "Error"
- `grep "NotAuthorized"`: get the lines containing "NotAuthorized"
- `grep -v "XXX"`: get the lines not containing "XXX"

Answer (score 1):

It looks fine to me. Just cross check if you are using all of these conditions:

```
grep "^Error" $file | grep "NotAuthorized" | grep -Ev "31071|13024"
     ^^^^^^^                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     lines starting with Error      |                       |
                 containing NotAuthorized
                             exclude either lines containing 31071 or 13024
```

To know which file is it happening in, use `-H` option in grep:

```
grep -H "^Error" $file | grep "NotAuthorized" | grep -Ev "31071|13024"
```

So all together you can do:

```
grep -H "^Error" /var/log/homes/* | grep "NotAuthorized" | grep -Ev "31071|13024"
```

Comment: ignore...I think I got it. Thanks, guys.

Answer (score 0):

Print any lines that start with 'Error' and contain the word 'NotAuthorized' and does not contain '13024' or '31071':

```
sed -n '/^Error/{/NotAuthorized/{/13024/!{/31071/!p}}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

This `awk` may do:

```
awk '/^Error/ && /NotAuthorized/ && !/31071|13024/' $logfile
```